# Adding pins/points to Choropleth Map D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to add pins or points or some circle to choropleth Map in D3JS. I am not sure how to do it. Can you please help?

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: I just got it working by var projection=d3.geo.albersUsa();
var coords=projection(['-77.679863', '43.088015']);

var sample=states.append('svg:circle')
.attr('cx',coords[0])
.attr('cy',coords[1])
.attr('r',1)
.style('fill','red');

Comment: Please help me use some other pin with tool tip attached to it. Do we have any svg component for the same?